# Is it possible to rename root "www" folder of the phonegap / cordova project?

Tags: cordova

Basically, is it possible to rename root **www** folder of the hybrid mobile project? I wasn't able to find any relevant info in the docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it is not possible to do this. You can however have another folder with your source code, and when running the application copy the files from the source code folder to your www folder. When you do this you can create the folder structure you want.

This way you can also do conversions, minification and other operation in your code without altering your original source code.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Could you give me an example of this approach with another folder (is someone using it?). I can't understand the idea of the copying files from custom folder to 'www'. Why one will do it?

Comment: This is usefull when you use build script runners like Grunt. Your www folder will then be your output folder (bin folder). It is not uncommon to use it that way. Indeed, you do not want to copy the files from source to www manually. It is not usefull if you do not use build script runners like Grunt. Why do you want to rename the www folder specifically?

Comment: Thanks, great answer! I'm writing a ripple based emulator and wanted to know info about possibility to define root folder for the project.